# How can I reduce repetitive config settings?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I am working on a Solution that contains several projects. There are several app.config files and several Settings.settings files.

This makes the task of finding all the settings and updating them somewhat tedious.

In the spirit of DRY programming, how can I reduce all these to a single file, preferable configurable by the user at runtime?

Comment: Have you tried creating single app.config file in solution root folder and then just adding it as a link to all required projects? I'm not sure this would work, just a wild guess...

Comment: In library projects the app.config settings never come into play. The whole file does nothing that I'm aware of. Just ignore it. If a tool automatically modifies that file, just let it do what it wants.

Comment: I'm guessing Steve might have multiple Win forms soulutions, for example, with same set of settings. He just switches between them, setting the StartUp project in Solutions explorer. If so, this could be a solution to have one configuration file for multiple similar projects.

Comment: No, I have one Solution, containing 6 projects. One is a Class Library, one is a Setup project. The rest are Windows Applications.

Comment: If these Windows applications do not share config files, then you shouldn't care about syncronizing all app.config files - as @usr said, app.config file matters only in current running project, and not in class libraries. As for runtime update - this is not supported from the box, I guess. You'll have to come up with some custom solution (storing settings, updating UI on settings change).